# Teclado virtual em HTML5 e JS

Tags: javascript, html5

Olá,

Estou precisando de ajuda na construção de um teclado numérico virtual em HTML5 e `JS`, para um site mobile, porem o campo `input` numérico ao ser clicado não pode acionar o teclado padrão do dispositivo, como se o `input` não fosse um campo editável para o navegador e sim somente para o teclado virtual.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos.

Comment: Poste o código.

Comment: Porque é que não trocas o campo input por outro qualquer, como um botão, e quando clicado abre então esse teu teclado virutal (que, suponho que seja feito por botoes em vez de input)

Comment: @MoshMage, o teclado numérico não e o problema, o problema e quanto eu clico no 'input' o teclado do celular aparece automaticamente e é isso queria evitar, para que o usuário utilizasse o teclado que eu fiz e não o teclado padrão do celular.

Answer (score 1):

Procurando "virtual keyboard javascript" no google encontrei isso:
https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/